# Why get only local data instead of all data of the cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

I have 3 shards 1 replica for my clickhouse cluster(3 nodes).  And i create a table using follow ddl on node1:

```
CREATE TABLE partition_v3_cluster ON CLUSTER perftest_3shards_3replicas(
ID String,
URL String,
EventTime Date
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(EventTime)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Then i execute the follow sqls one for one node:

```
INSERT INTO partition_v3_cluster VALUES ('A0001','www.nauu.com', '2019-10-01');
INSERT INTO partition_v3_cluster VALUES ('A0002','www.nauu.com', '2019-10-02');
INSERT INTO partition_v3_cluster VALUES ('A0003','www.nauu.com', '2019-10-03');
```

When query in all the 3 nodes respectively:

```
select * from partition_v3_cluster;
```

every node just get the record insert before that executed on each node:
for example node1:

```
┌─ID────┬─URL──────────┬──EventTime─┐
│ A0001 │ www.nauu.com │ 2019-10-01 │
└───────┴──────────────┴────────────┘
```

Shouldn't get all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create DISTRIBUTED tables.

https://kb.altinity.com/engines

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DlQ6sVKQaA&t=17s